# No Python Interpreter is selected in Pycharm (and no project is selected)

Tags: python, git, pycharm, interpreter

I have this weird error I keep getting when I open projects from GitHub. I get this error : "no Python interpreter is selected". And when I go to settings, I don't even find "Project interpreter". It's like PyCharm doesn't recognize my project. I have two python versions 3.8 and 3.9 and they show up both when I create a new project but when I open a ready project I don't get to select any of them.

[Project interpreter is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36T49.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for your interpreter (python.exe) by going to add under interpreter if it is not displayed there.

[1) Open Interpreter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1yxI.png)
[2) Select Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFS5l.png)

Comment: I don't see the interpreter tab there, I have instead another tab called "main"

Comment: Is there really nothing? 
[Image](https://ibb.co/9ykTGCT).
Can you possibly upload a screenshot?